# Запись колонки таблицы sql в тхт формате в php

Tags: php, mysql

Как с помощью php записать данные конкретной колонки таблицы sql в txt файле, так чтобы если этот файл существует, перезаписывался?

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php

    $fh = fopen($path, 'w');
    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "my_password", "my_db");
    mysql_select_db("db_name", $con);

    /* insert field values into data.txt */

    $result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT [column name] FROM [table name]");   
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {          
        $last = end($row);          
        $num = mysqli_num_fields($result) ;    
        for($i = 0; $i < $num; $i++) {            
            fwrite($fh, $row[$i]);                      
            if ($row[$i] != $last)
               fwrite($fh, ", ");
        }                                                                 
        fwrite($fh, "\n");
    }
    fclose($fh);
?>
```

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_connect() in C:\OpenServer\domains\msg\users\test\EXPORT_TXT_FAIL.php:5 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in

Comment: $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "my_password", "my_db");

Comment: Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in C:\OpenServer\domains\msg\users\test\EXPORT_TXT_FAIL.php on line 10

Comment: mysqli_query($con, "SELECT [column name] FROM [table name]"), будьте добры, указывайте версию php в своем вопросе

Comment: Учту. Спасибо, все заработало.